# Parse Issue: Expected Expression (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, macos, tableview

For what ever reason my xcode has decided it doesn't like me... I'm getting the error stated in the title on this line

```
- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSInteger row = [_tableView selectedRow];
    if (row == –1) //<---- this line
    {
        return;
    }
    NSString *selectedVoice = [_voices objectAtIndex:row];
    [_speechSynth setVoice:selectedVoice];
    NSLog(@"new voice = %@", selectedVoice);
}
```

I do believe that it has something to do with _tableView being befuddled because when I attempted to get the IDE to help me to type (you know when it guesses what you might what to finish your word with by doing an API lookup of available functions) it doesn't show selectedRow as a possibility :(

incase it's needed i've put the .m and .h in a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/4gMcYd1K) to save some space on your screens... FYI I'm following the Coca Programming for Mac OSX fourth Edition chapter 6.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your line

```
if (row == –1)
```

the minus-sign is not the real minus-sign, but an "EN DASH" (Unicode U+2013). Perhaps you accidentally pressed the option-key together with the minus-key when typing that code.

Replacing that character with a minus-sign fixes the problem.

Comment: I've typed a million if statements in my life.. so when the book said to type this I may or may not have coppy/pated out of the pdf because I was getting a tinsy bit bored of basic flow -.- atleast I now know what that error means.. thanks

Comment: @MichaelCrook: Yes, copy/paste from PDF is a potential problem, perhaps the code was typeset by a designer :-). Sometimes you see typographical quotes `“...”` for strings.

Answer (score 0):

UITableView doesn't have a method called selectedRow.

Perhaps you should be using:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForSelectedRow
```

Comment: This is Mac OS X, not iOS. `NSTableView` *does* have such a method.